# How to explain this behaviour of JSF and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

With the following code the status `ERROR` is alerted. When I put the `commandButton` outside the form OR put another `alert()` at the end of `geocode()` status `OK` will be alerted.
What happens here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
    var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function geocode() {
        geocoder.geocode({'address' : 'china'},geocoderCallback);
    }

    function geocoderCallback(results, status) {
        alert(status);
        };
    </script>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
    <h:commandButton onclick="geocode()" value="geocode" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For start change your code from

```
onclick="geocode()"
```

into

```
onclick="geocode(); return false;"
```

The reason of that behavior is because when the `<h:commandButton` located inside the `h:form` (and you are not using the `f:ajax`) you are doing an *entire page submit*

As a result of  that *entire page submit* a page reload will occur (and that what messes the maps), and after that reload your callback('geocoderCallback') is being called

if you move the `<h:commandButton` outside the `h:form` it won't do any page submit and only call the js code and in this case all is ok (your maps are not "messed")

same goes for the *" another alert() at the end of geocode()"* it will show the alert before the page submit (before your maps are "messed")

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Now it works and even starts to make more sense, but I still don't really get it: How does this part after the page reload work? I would have supposed that just "no one" listens to a response from the geocoding server anymore. I also think The status `ERROR` implies that something was wrong with some request. But the request itself should have been fine.

Comment: Geocoder runs apparently asynchronously. So once it's triggered and executed in a different thread, then the current thread immediately returns to continue button's `onclick` behavior of synchronously submitting the form. This step in turn aborts all running asynhronous calls on the current page. The geocoder call then results in an error.

Comment: So the status `ERROR` does not come from the geocoding server but from the script that was loaded to my client?